# Finding reciprocal ties in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, networking

I have a MongoDB collection with about half a billion documents consisting of two ints (a, b). These are basically ties in a network. I want to return all the reciprocal ties, i.e all the documents (a1, b1) where there exists in the collection another document (a2, b2) such that (a2=b1, b2=a1). Is this possible to do in Mongo? I've scoured the manuals, but as an old relational db hound I'm finding the mongo syntax quite a struggle.

(I would do this programmatically, but complicating matters is that I don't have enough RAM or hard disk space to store a copy of all the entries, so I have to do this internally in the database. Or, I guess, buy a new hard drive.)

Comment: You don't have to store all entries in RAM: you can retrieve them block-wise, eg. compare all entries where  0 <= a < 1 with all entries where 0<= b < 1 (or whatever range suits your RAM): the reciprocal ties can only be in those two sets.

Comment: Thanks, @lysium, that's very clever! It would however feel a lot cleaner to do it in mongo...

Comment: I don't see any way of referencing other documents within a mongodb query besides querying these other documents beforehand.